# Spark dataframe groupby unique values in a column

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe:

```
val df = Seq(
    ("A", 2.0),
    ("A", 1.5),
    ("B", 8.0),
    ("B", 9.0)
  ).toDF("id", "val")
```

I would like to do a group and for each group based on the unique ID
1. have a running count, ie first one is 0, second is 1
2. a total count inside the group.

should look like

```
+---+---+---+---+
| id|val|order|count|
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|2.0|0 |2
|  A|1.5|1 |2
|  A|2.5|2 |2
|  B|8.0|0|2
|  B|9.0|1 |2
+---+---+
```

I don't see how to do this with the spark sql or functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.

Input Data:

```
+---+---+
|id |val|
+---+---+
|A  |2.0|
|A  |1.5|
|A  |4.5|
|A  |0.5|
|B  |8.0|
|B  |9.0|
+---+---+
```

Use row_number function to get the order count.

```
val w1 = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(lit(null))

df.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(w1))
  .withColumn("order", 'rank - 1)
  .withColumn("count",count('order).over(w1))
  .drop('rank)
  .orderBy('id)
  .show(false)
```

Both give the same result:

```
+---+---+-----+-----+
|id |val|order|count|
+---+---+-----+-----+
|A  |2.0|0    |4    |
|A  |1.5|1    |4    |
|A  |4.5|2    |4    |
|A  |0.5|3    |4    |
|B  |8.0|0    |2    |
|B  |9.0|1    |2    |
+---+---+-----+-----+
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, it looks like it would work. I'm using stuct streaming also by the way.

Comment: the order in your example will not work. for example when there is 4 it must count to the correct number.

Comment: Updated the answer. Good Luck! Again, still my answer on the assumption as the expected result is 100% not clear

Comment: Post a different question on what you are facing.